# Django: list object is not callable in forms.py using validators and RegexValidator

Tags: python, django

I’m trying to add a RegexValidator validator to a contact form (forms.py) to prevent spammers from adding `http://` and `https://` links in the message.

I’ve included `from django.core.validators import RegexValidator` at the top of `forms.py`.

This example of general_message works fine when not using the validator:

```
general_message = forms.CharField(label='General message*', required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': '1000', 'rows': 8}
    ))
```

But I get the error `'list’ object is not callable` in the example below:

```
general_message = forms.CharField(label='General message*', required=True, widget=forms.Textarea, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^(?!.*\bhttps?\b).+$', message="No http or https allowed", code="invalid")] (
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': '1000', 'rows': 8} ))
```

It appears I have my brackets and parentheses correct. What causes the error?

Python 3.9, Django 4.0.1

---

Edit 4/20/22: the Regex does match `http://` and `https://`

Comment: You've inserted it in the middle of the `widget` code - `widget=TextArea<validator_here?>()`

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `CharField` with a `TextArea` widget rather than just using a `TextField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest using a `TextField` instead of `CharField`. General `CharField` is intended for a small snippet of text and `TextField` is for a large text.

If you insist on using a `CharField`, you should format this long line of code in such a way that you can understand what it does. For example:

```
general_message = forms.CharField(
    label='General message*', 
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Textarea, 
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            regex=r'http(s)?|HTTP(s)?',
            message="No http or https allowed",
            code="invalid"
        )
    ]
    (
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'maxlength': '1000',
            'rows': 8
        }
    )
)
```

Now you see that you have a `()` immediately after the `[]` for `validators`. This looks like a function call. But that doesn't make any sense since you cannot call a list, as the error says.

By using consistent formatting and indentation, you can easily avoid these kinds of problems. The format I show above is one of many styles that can work. Just pick something and stick with it.

To fix this, you need to just move the code around so it lines up correctly. It looks like you put the `validators` in the wrong place in between `Textarea` and the `()` to call its constructor. The correct code should be like this:

```
general_message = forms.CharField(
    label='General message*', 
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'maxlength': '1000',
            'rows': 8
        }
    ),
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            regex=r'http(s)?|HTTP(s)?',
            message="No http or https allowed",
            code="invalid"
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Formatting code makes a lot of sense, and now I see what I did wrong. Your corrected code throws no errors, but now I find that my regex doesn't work, but that's a different issue. I'm using CharField because a contact form example I found used that; with a TextField, can I still limit text to a maxlength?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch To be clear, I suggest using `models.TextField` in your model. It will automatically generate a `Textarea` widget when used with a `ModelForm`.

Comment: Nix that...yes, you can specify a `maxlength` directly on the model field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#textfield

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using a model at all; only a forms.py file. The only code in my models.py is `from django.db import models`

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Also, you should put the validator on the model field rather than the form field. This will cause validation no matter how the model object is created or edited.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Oh...well, after looking a little closer, there is no `forms.TextField`, so maybe that doesn't apply. Why don't you have a model? Are you not saving the entered data anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This app is a simple contact form that POSTS via an SMTP server; I'm not using a database at all.